# Method for renderTo EXTJS on mainView

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I trying renderTo a panel(Ext.panel with title:'titlet' in the end of code) to the mainView ('Foresto.view.main.Main') or to a part of courusel (id:'mapId') But i havn't got a positive result. 
So my quistions: 
1) How to render panel to  the mainview or to a courusel item ('mapId')
2)What mains approaches in Ext JS 6+, modern toolkit, for render object to the mainview or mainview's elements??

Now my code looks like that:

```
 Ext.define('Foresto.view.main.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
id:"control-panel",
plugins: 'responsive',
responsiveConfig:{
    tall:{
        tabPosition:'center'
    }
},
xtype: 'app-main',
controller:'menuform',     
requires: [
    'Foresto.view.map.Map',
    'Foresto.view.main.ButtonController',
    'Foresto.view.forms.LoginRoom'

],
autosize:true,
padding: 0,
id:"bighBox",
header: {
    cls: 'header-cls',
    title : {
        cls : 'header-title-cls',
        text : 'FOREST'
    }
},
tools: [{
    type: 'menu',
    handler: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.toggleMenu('top');
    }
    }],

items:[{
    xtype: 'carousel',
    id: "mainPart",
    flex: 1,
    defaults: {
        border: true,
        ui: 'light'
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'MAP',

        id:'mapId',
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout:'vbox',
        padding: 0,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title:'PLACEFORMAP'
        }]


    },{
        title: 'REPORTS',
        xtype: 'panel',
        cls: 'foresBack',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'middle',
            pack: 'center'
        },

        items:[{
            xtype:'button',
            cls:'threethbutton',
            ui: 'confirm',
            text:'REPORT1',
            margin:'10px'

        },{
            xtype:'button',
            cls:'threethbutton',
            ui: 'confirm',
            text:'REPORT2'
        }]
    }]
}

    ],
```

initialize: function() {

```
    Ext.Viewport.add({
          xtype:'button',
          id:'pan11111',
          text:'KAB',
          flex:1,
          height: 1000,
          width: 100,
          items:[{
              xtype:'tabpanel',
              title:'Projects',
              layout:'card',
              items:[{
                  xtype:'panel',
                  title:'11111'
              },{
                  xtype:'panel',
                  title:'uuuuu'
              }]
          }]
      });

}
}});
```

Comment: now I edit function for rendering panel on viewport. Panel 'pan11111' is rendering, bu viewport cover all other elements, and I can work only with panel and white board viewport, witch cover all classes:

Answer (score 0):

now I edit function for rendering panel on viewport. Panel 'pan11111' is rendering, bu viewport cover all other elements, and I can work only with panel and white board viewport, witch cover all classes: –THIS problem was solved by great clearning of coockies